# How to use abstract class' children instances through methods?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I have an abstract class Player and its children AI and Human. In my main, when I create two objects Human and AI it works fine. But once I use them as parameters in a function that is waiting for Player pointer type, then their type is no longer AI and Human but both are Player objects.

Game.hpp :

```
#include "Player.hpp"
#include "Human.hpp"

class Game {
private:
    Player *j1, *j2;

public:
    Game();
    Game(Player*, Player*);
    void setP1(Player*);
    void setP2(Player*);
    Player* getP1();
    Player* getP2();
};
```

Game.cpp :

```
 #include "Game.hpp"

 Game::Game(){

}

Game::Game(Player *pp1, Player *pp2){
p1 = pp1;
p2 = pp2;
}

void Game::setP1(Player *pp1){
p1 = pp1;
}

void Game::setP2(Player *pp2){
p2 = pp2;
}

Player* Game::getP1(){
return p1;
}

Player* Game::getP2(){
return p2;
}
```

Player.hpp :

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <string>

using std::string;

class Player {
protected:
    string nom;
    int age;

public:
    Player();
    Player(string, int);
    void setNom(string);
    void setAge(int);
    string getNom();
    int getAge();

    virtual void upAge() = 0;
};

#endif
```

Here is the main.cpp :

```
#include "Player.hpp"
#include "Human.hpp"
#include "Game.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(){
Player *j;
Human h;
Game Game;

cout << typeid(h).name() << endl;
Game.setJ1(&h);
cout << typeid(Game.getJ1()).name() << endl;



return 0;
}
```

I would like the two cout to display the same result. But the first displays Human, and the second displays Player. How can I handle this ?

EDIT 1 : added Player.hpp file.

Comment: I believe there's a lot of completely unrelated code. Please delete it and provide a [mcve] reproducing your problem.

Comment: I tried to take off what is useless. But I think what is left can be usefull to understand.

Comment: Please show us the header Player.hpp. I guess that the methods were not declared virtual. When the methods in the base class are declared virtual, the methods of child classes are called through pointers or references to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Base class `Player` must contain a virtual function to get the type name as derived class.

check [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) below example from cpp reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Base {}; // non-polymorphic
struct Derived : Base {};

struct Base2 { virtual void foo() {} }; // polymorphic
struct Derived2 : Base2 {};

int main() {

    // Non-polymorphic lvalue is a static type
    Derived d1;
    Base& b1 = d1;
    std::cout << "reference to non-polymorphic base: " << typeid(b1).name() << '\n';

    Derived2 d2;
    Base2& b2 = d2;
    std::cout << "reference to polymorphic base: " << typeid(b2).name() << '\n';
 }
```

---

Possible output:

```
reference to non-polymorphic base: 4Base
reference to polymorphic base: 8Derived2
```

Comment: I don't get it. My goal is simply to set the variable j1 from class Game as a Human, since it's a children class.

Comment: What about upAge()? It's virtual function from Player isnt it ?

Comment: You want the typeid result from both couts must be the same. For this, base class i.e Player must NOT contain virtual function. please remove virtual functions in the base.